# Learner in R to predict data from a complex function: if a>b then a*b else a+b

Tags: r, likelihood, supervised-learning

What sort of general purpose learner could learn the data generated by the following function:  if a>b then a*b else a+b or something of that sort of complexity. Ideally something general enough to be included in caret, basically well studied general purpose learner.

Comment: To clarify: We are given data, 2 predictors (A and B) and 1 response variable C. The true underlying function is if a>b then a*b else a+b. So for instance if a is 5 and b is 2 then the response C is 10. However is a is 2 and b is 5, the response C is 7. However we do not know the form of the true function, we only have the data. Which supervised learning technique could produce a prediction function which best minimizes the error of our data i.e. learn the underlying function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not  sure that I fully understand what you are looking for but this package could be it:

[rgp: R genetic programming framework](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/index.html)

The best starting point is to have a look at the vignette:

[A Friendly Introduction to RGP](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp/vignettes/rgp_introduction.pdf)